# Boolean expression in Java

Tags: java

I'm starting to learn about boolean expressions. I am trying to figure out the following question:

> Suppose age1, age2, and age3 are int variables, and suppose answer is a boolean variable. Write an expression that assigns answer the value true exactly when age1 is less than or equal to age2 AND age2 is less than or equal to age3. Otherwise answer should be assigned false.

I have tried a few things but am relatively new to Java. I am able to make the answer print True but something is still wrong with my numbers.

This is wrong:

```
age1=7;
age2=10;
age3=12;
boolean a= (age1<=age2);
boolean b= (age2<=age3);
boolean answer= (a&&b);
```

I'm just not sure how to fix this or what exactly is going on in the code; what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What makes you think it's wrong?

Comment: I am using an online learning website for my college. When I enter that code it says I'm wrong. The following feedback pops up: Feedback:
Your code failed for age1=5, age2=7, and age3=2

Comment: Maybe it just thinks you didn't declare ages as ints

Comment: Perhaps it is wrong format. Maybe it doesn't like the two extra variables, `a` and `b`. To avoid using those, you can do `boolean answer = age1 <= age2 && age2 <= age3;`

Comment: Well the code is correct for the purpose (assuming you've left out the int declaration just in the question). They're probably looking for you to not use the a and b variables to store the individual booleans.  `boolean answer= (age1<=age2)&&(age2<=age3);` is fine in that case.

Comment: Or, since it says "write an expression", it might just want the expression, in which case just input `age1 <= age2 && age2 <= age3`. Or `boolean answer = age1 <= age2 && age2 <= age3;`

Comment: If I were to implement a validator for this, I would assign test values for age1, age2, and age3, run the code, and check result for "answer".  If you're reassigning age1, age2, and age3, it may work, but answer will be different than the validator is expecting.

Comment: Thank you everyone. I was entering it in the wrong format I guess because it was asking for an expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code your given should work perfectly.

```
age1=7;
age2=10;
age3=12;
boolean a= (age1<=age2);
boolean b= (age2<=age3);
boolean answer= (a&&b);
```

But as the questions specifies an "expression" try this out:

```
boolean answer=age1<=age2 && age2<=age3;
```

Comment: Actually, you can leave the brackets out.

Comment: @MinecraftShamrock oops ! edited my answer , but shouldnt it work with the brackets also?

Comment: @MohitBhasi Sure, it works with and without brackets. But they are optional here because `<=` has a higher precedence than `&&`. See [Java Precedence Table](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html)

Comment: @MinecraftShamrock oo yea! completely forgot about the precedence :P